# Mikro ORM migration command returning config not found errror

Tags: typescript, orm, mikro-orm

I am following Ben Awad's full stack tutorial: [youtube tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6ypD7qv3Z8&t=1390s&ab_channel=BenAwad) . Around minute 30 is relevant.

The command `npx mikro-orm migration:create` is giving an error for me.
The error is:

```
Error: MikroORM config file not found in ['./dist/mikro-orm.config.js', './mikro-orm.config.js']
    at Function.getConfiguration (/Users/username/lireddit-server/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/utils/ConfigurationLoader.js:44:15)
    at async Function.getORM (/Users/username/lireddit-server/node_modules/@mikro-orm/cli/CLIHelper.js:22:25)
    at async Function.handleMigrationCommand (/Users/username/lireddit-server/node_modules/@mikro-orm/cli/commands/MigrationCommandFactory.js:68:21)
```

I believe the error might be that it is looking at './mikro-orm.config.js' which I don't think exists, instead of './mikro-orm.config.ts' which exists and is shown below.

There is a 'mikro-orm.config.ts' file:

```
import { Options } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import path from "path";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";

const config: Options = {
  migrations: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "./migrations"),
    glob: "!(*.d).{js,ts}",
  },
  entities: [Post],
  dbName: "lireddit",
  user: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  type: "postgresql",
  debug: !__prod__,
};

export default config;
```

In the tutorial 'pattern' is used instead of 'glob' in the 'migrations' object. I used 'glob' because 'pattern' is now deprecated.

This is the 'package.json'. Here the last object, 'mikro-orm' is relevant.

```
{
  "name": "lireddit-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "nodemon dist/index.js",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "start2": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "dev2": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.8.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mikro-orm/cli": "^5.4.2",
    "@mikro-orm/core": "^5.4.2",
    "@mikro-orm/migrations": "^5.4.2",
    "@mikro-orm/postgresql": "^5.4.2",
    "pg": "^8.8.0"
  },
  "mikro-orm": {
    "useTsNode": true,
    "configPaths": [
      "./src/mikro-orm.config.ts",
      "./dist/mikro-orm.config.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the index.ts:

```
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { profileEnd } from "console";
import { userInfo } from "os";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
import microConfig from "./mikro-orm.config";

const main = async () => {
  const orm = await MikroORM.init(microConfig);

  const post = orm.em.create(Post, { title: "first post" });
  await orm.em.persistAndFlush(post);
  console.log("--------sql2---------");
  await orm.em.nativeInsert(Post, { title: "my first post" });
};

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

console.log("hello world");
```

This is 'post.ts':

```
import { Entity, PrimaryKey, Property } from "@mikro-orm/core";

@Entity()
export class Post {
  @PrimaryKey()
  id!: number;

  @Property()
  createdAt? = new Date();

  @Property({ onUpdate: () => new Date() })
  updatedAt? = new Date();

  @Property()
  title!: string;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `ts-node`, otherwise, you don't have TS support and any `.ts` config file will be ignored.